# Hardness of Maximum Independent Set in 3-Colorable Graphs

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, approximation-hardness, graph-colouring, independent-set

Let $G = (V,E)$ be an undirected graph such that there is a proper coloring of the vertices of $G$ in three colors.

**Question:** In such graphs, are there known results for the hardness of finding a maximum independent set? e.g., can one find an Independent set of cardinality at least  $\varepsilon \cdot |V|$ in polynomial time for some constant $\varepsilon>0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As detailed below, the problem of finding an independent set of size $\Omega(n^{1-\delta})$ in 3-colorable graphs is essentially equivalent to $O(n^\delta)$-approximating 3-COLOR.  Currently, the best poly-time approximation ratio known to be achievable for 3-COLOR is $O(n^\delta)$ for $\delta>0.19$.  If you could find independent sets of size $\Omega(n^{0.81})$ in 3-colorable graphs in polynomial time, you could achieve a poly-time  approximation ratio of $O(n^{0.19})$ for 3-COLOR, beating the best current ratio.

(Here, by *$f(n)$-approximating 3-COLOR*, I mean the following problem: *given a 3-colorable graph with $n$ vertices, find a coloring of size at most $3f(n)$.*

**Lemma 1.** *Fix any constant $\delta>0$. There is a poly-time $O(n^\delta)$-approximation algorithm for 3-COLOR if and only if there is a poly-time algorithm for finding an independent set of size $\Omega(n^{1-\delta})$ in any given 3-colorable graph.*

*Proof.*
The "only if" direction is easy. Just compute a coloring that uses at most $O(n^\delta)$ colors and return the largest color class.  This is necessarily an independent set of size at least $\Omega(n/n^{\delta}) = \Omega(n^{1-\delta})$.

The "if" direction is not much harder.  Suppose that algorithm $A$ finds an independent set of size $\Omega(n^{1-\delta})$ in any given 3-colorable graph in polynomial time.  Given a graph $G=(V, E)$, define algorithm $B$ to find a coloring for $G$ as follows: use $A$ to find a large independent set $S$ in $G$, recurse on the graph $G'$ obtained by deleting the vertices in $S$ from $G$ to find a coloring of $G'$, then add $S$ as a new color to this coloring to produce a coloring of $G$.  (Of course the base case is when the graph has no vertices.)  Note that $G'$ is 3-colorable, so the algorithm is well-defined.

Let $C(n)$ be the maximum number of colors $B$ uses to color any 3-colorable $n$-vertex graph.  Then $C(0) = 0$ and for $n\ge 1$ we have
$$C(n) \le 1 + C(\lfloor n - \Omega(n^{1-\delta})\rfloor).$$
Expanding the recurrence $O((n/2)^\delta)$ times
until the argument has size at most $n/2$ we have
$$C(n) \le O((n/2)^\delta) + C(n/2).$$
Expanding this in turn gives the bound
$C(n) \le O\big(\sum_{i\ge 1} (n/2^i)^\delta\big) = O(n^\delta/\delta) = O(n^\delta).~~~~~\Box$

The best poly-time approximation algorithms known for 3-COLOR [are apparently](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/144733/currently-best-approximation-for-graph-coloring) $O(n^{\delta})$-approximation algorithms for $\delta > 0.19$.  (For a good survey of these results see the introduction of [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1145/3001582).)  If you could find independent sets of size $\Omega(n^{0.81})$ in 3-colorable graphs in polynomial time, this would directly yield an $O(n^{0.19})$-approximation algorithm for 3-COLOR, better than these currently known results.

For graph coloring in general, Lund and Yannakakis [showed](https://doi.org/10.1145/185675.306789) that, unless P=NP, for some constant $\delta > 0$, there is no polynomial-time $O(n^\delta)$-approximation algorithm for coloring. This may hold for 3-COLOR as well, but as far as I know this has not yet been shown.  A quick search turns up a couple of recent hardness results: [this](https://doi.org/10.1137/1.9781611975994.86) and [this](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C22&q=d-To-1+Hardness+of+Coloring+3-Colorable+Graphs+with+O(1)+Colors).

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question and for the detailed survey. A follow-up question if I may: Would the problem remains as hard (or, at least without a known algorithm) if each vertex $v \in V$ has a degree at least $d(v) \geq \Omega(\delta \cdot n)$?

Comment: Not as hard, I think.  For example, you could do something like the following.  Given a 3-colorable graph $G$, let $d$ be the maximum degree of any vertex in $G$ and let $v$ be a vertex of degree $d$.  Find a 2-coloring $C$ of the neighbor set of $v$ (this must exist and can be found in linear time).  Return the larger of the two color classes in $C$.  Then each color class in $C$ is an independent set, and the largest one has size at least $d/2$, so this linear-time algorithm returns an independent set of size at least $d/2$.  In your case this is $\Omega(\delta n)$.  Probably can do better.

Comment: Thank you!, this was helpful:)